# How to take in reactive components to ggvis without making itself reactive in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a ggvis plot in an app that needs to modify its axis title based on a user input. I do this in the way I show below: by putting ggvis object inside a reactive block

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    frame = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3))

    title = reactive({
        input$userInput
    })

    reactive({
        frame %>% 
            ggvis(~a, ~b) %>% 
            add_axis('y', title = title()) %>%
            layer_points()
    }) %>% bind_shiny('plot')
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                textInput(inputId = 'userInput',
                          label = 'y axis title')
        ),
        mainPanel(
            ggvisOutput('plot')
        ))))
```

I don't want to do this because this resets the entire plot at every change (which resets the size, prevents you from having the nice sliding effect that ggvis has and have other downsides). Is there a way to have ggvis only change the only property I want it to change in this context?